# d3.js 404 json file not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, http-status-code-404

I am trying to use d3.js example code here: https://bl.ocks.org/ChumaA/385a269db46ae56444772b62f1ae82bf

In this case I am using view jade/express/node to load it, however I am getting a 404 error for the mockelasticdata.json file, I believe I am routing it correctly. I provided photos to show the directory path and the chrome console error.

Console Error:
[image: console error]

Directory Path:
[image: directory path]

edit: here is the json call using d3 to read the data

```js
      d3.json('src/mockelasticdata.json', function(error, mockdata) {
          if (error) return console.error(error);
          console.log('mockdata',mockdata);
          mapdata = mockdata;
          draw(mockdata)
      });
```

Comment: While your issue was simple to identify from the information you provided, you shouldn't post a screen screenshot of code when asking for help - It makes identifying problems much more difficult.  
[Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1018580).

Comment: thanks, i'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access a file in the src directory.  After your project is built and run, that directory doesn't exist.

Move the JSON file into the public directory.  This is where all static, unrouted files will be served from.